# Linux distribution for Lenovo Yoga 3 14 (extensive touchscreen support)

Tags: linux-distribution, touchscreen

I am looking for a Linux distribution for Lenovo Yoga 3 14. Ideally, the distribution should support:

Yoga has a touch screen and can rotate its screen to become a tablet - I would like to take advantage of it.

I'd love to be able to easily use a web browser when in tablet mode. I am looking for a distro which supports the following features:

- two-finger scrolling
- on-screen keyboard when inside a text field
- gestures to go to the previous page
- rotating the screen
- disabling the keyboard and the touchpad when in the tablet mode

I've read that features like scrolling are supported on the browser level in Firefox (with the [Grab and Drag plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/grab-and-drag/)) and Chromium. The touchscreen is well supported by Gnome, KDE and Unity from what I read.

Personally, I've tested Ubuntu 16.04 with Gnome and Ubuntu 16.10 with Unity neither of which felt *right* in the tablet mode.

---

Related:

- [Setting up Linux for a touch-screen laptop](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/10628/setting-up-linux-for-a-touch-screen-laptop)
- [Desktop environment for a touchscreen 2-in-1 laptop for an Ubuntu system](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/31626/desktop-environment-for-a-touchscreen-2-in-1-laptop-for-an-ubuntu-system/31967#31967)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu 17.04 Zesty Zapus with its Unity 8 is going to be the distribution I was looking for. I've just tested Unity 8 and its touchscreen support is awesome.

Comment: The sad thing is that Unity 8 support has been dropped.